# Noop() is called when invoking $scope.$apply() in angular promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I am racking my brain on why $scope.$apply() inside my callback is not working. As per my understanding $scope.$apply()is used to update a view/page when data changes in callback from an asynchronous call.

In my case,I want to update a progress bar as CRMData asynchronous service returns a pageful of records. When I update the progressIndicator inside $scope.$apply(), the value of progressIndicator is not updated in the view.

Stepping into $scope.$apply() inside the success callback on promise, I was surprised that it is a noop().

My view where the controller function is called from ng-init.

```
   <div ng-controller="OpptyCtrl"  ng-init="getOpptyByPage(0,50)" >
      <div>
        <progressbar value="progressIndicator" ></progressbar>  
      </div>
   </div>
```

My controller:

```
  .controller('OpptyCtrl'['$scope','crmData', '$q',function($scope,crmData,$q) {
      $scope.user='user';

     $scope.getOpptyByPage = function(startIndex,pageSize) {
        crmData.getOpptyByPage($q,$scope.user,startIndex)                                               
          .then(function (result) {    //On getting a pageful of records         
             if(result.noMoreRecords == "false"){  //more records 
                startIndex += pageSize;  
                $scope.getOpptyByPage(startIndex,pageSize); 
                   $scope.$apply(function() { // <<-- is a noop
                   $scope.progressIndicator=(startIndex/result.totalRecords);
                });
              }
       });
  }
```

Any pointers will help.

Comment: When a `$scope` is destroyed its `$apply` method is set to noop. Try `console.log($scope.$$destroyed)` to see if that is the case.

Comment: I don't think this has much to do with promises. Also I find the `== "false"` comparison really disturbing what are you trying to do there?

Comment: Benjamin, The result object is a json response from the asynchronous service and contains a string "false" if there are more pages. When I run $scope.$apply()  in the controller outside of the .then callback, it is not a noop().The noop happens only inside the callback on the promise.